# Where can I find info on writing OLE servers using Win32 API only and not MFC?

Tags: c++, winapi, ole

I have a GUI application that is written in C and C++ wrapping Win32 API. I have to convert that into OLE server. I know what kind of design changes must be done or will figure it out. What I want is to know from you is how to go about implementing it. I googled but couldn't find even a brief tutorial outlining the necessary steps. I find mostly MFC stuff. I couldn't find the proper msdn page either (not sure if it exists).

I know basics of COM. I just want a quick start up guide, with preferably an example involving a GUI application, and I can take it from there.

---

WOW! Just two minutes after posting this question it shows up when I google "ole server without mfc". Scary!

Comment: OLE is dead as a doornail, has been for the past 10 years.  Even if you could get one going, the odds that you'll find a programmer willing to use your server are zero.  High odds that you are using the wrong term btw.

Comment: What you say is true but I have to get this done and that is what I want to do! It seems best way to reuse our legacy software within our org with minimum fuss. The fact that its dead as doornail yet I can't find the info is surprising.

Comment: Not finding info on dead technology should never be surprising.

Comment: haha I meant because it was once alive and kicking yet no info now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kraig Brockschmidt's book "Inside OLE" is the bible on that.  You can find it pretty cheap used.  It's not dead technology.  Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and countless others use the technology.

Comment: We don't do book recommendations here. In fact, they're specifically mentioned as an off-topic question in the [help/on-topic] page - see item #4 in the numbered list on that page).

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks for a positive answer.

Comment: The whole book (Inside OLE) was included in the MSDN discs for VC++ 6. Is not available in MSDN online though.

Comment: The CD samples can be downloaded from the author's page (http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/books/). And yes, is not dead technology.